# Hibernate and Spring, load a collection that is in lazy mode

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, lazy-loading

I'm using Spring to manage transaction in my service layer with `@Transactional` annotation.
This is fine for eager loaded collection, but is bad for lazy loading.

**I cant use OSV pattern, my application is a standalone desktop client application.**

So I thought about a solution, and this is what I tried to do:

```
public abstract class TransactionTask {

    public TransactionTask() {
    }

    public abstract void job(); 
}
```

In my service I have:

```
@Transactional
public void doJob(Transactiontask tt){
    tt.job();
}
```

And how I use it is:

```
myService.doJob(new TransactionTask() {

    @Override
    public void job() {
        //lazy code here
    }
});
```

I expect to see this code work, becouse session is open in doJob method(it is marked as transactional), but it doesn't work...the exception is `no session or session was closed`.
Why this code doesn't work, and how can I load a collection only when i need it?

I do not want to write a service with a specified method to load collection, that is not a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Lazy Loading doesn't require just *a* session, it requires *the* session that your `Entity` is attached to.  You need to attach the objects to the new session created by `@Transactional` before you try to access the lazy fields.

Also, while you obviously cannot use one of the available OSIV servlet filters, the 'pattern' is still valid.  There has to be some definable scope that you can couple the lifecycle of a session to.  (It may prove to be so large that there are other challenges making it not worth the effort, but it is still an option.)

Answer (score 0):

E.g. you have `User user` object. It's detached that's why you got "the exception is no session or session was closed".

You can reread it from the dao `user=userDao.findById(user.getId())` and then get lazy collections of the newly retrieved object.